# Angular2 href issue for carousel next slide

Tags: angular, angular2-custom-component

I have a custom **`modal component`** which is responsible to display overlay(modal-popup) which contains carousel.

**Problem :** As you can see in below code, outer div contains **`(click)`** event to close the overlay (*`I dont have Header part in overlay`*).

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" (click)="hide($event)">              
          ...
          ...   

    <a  class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="sr-only">next</span>
     </a>

</div>
```

So when I click **`a tag`**, it hides overlay too. If I remove **click** event, carousel works fine.

To solve the problem, I've attached `(click)="stoppropogation($event);false"` to **`a tag`** to stop event propagation. Now clicking **`a tag`** doesn't hide overlay but it doesn't even show next picture.

Here is my code,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" (click)="hide($event)">

          ...
          ...

          <a  (click)="stoppropogation($event);false" id="next"  role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>

</div>



stoppropogation(event:any){
    event.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById("next").href="#myCarousel";
}
```

Any easy solution?

Comment: If you put `false` in the tag, it will both `stopPropogation` and `preventDefault`, can you remove the false and try again?  :/

Comment: I tried it that way too but it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens with only `stopPropogation` ?

Comment: It doesn't stop bubbling of an event.

Comment: I ended up using jquery which is not good. but its works.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with a smaller example in case someone want to play around: https://plnkr.co/edit/rMxQpsxPrBFRojne6LuK?p=preview if you click on next inside the modal the wrapper divs alert doesn't pop up as expected but not sure how yours doesn't work :/